# Lubuntu updater wants to install a lot of new Gnome 3 packages

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, lubuntu, lxde

I have turned on my old laptop with Lubuntu 16.04.3 for the first time this month and wanted to install new updates. To my surprise, using the updater application or apt-get dist-upgrade, it wants to install a lot of new Gnome 3 related packages and I don't know why.

This my `apt-get dist-upgrade` output: https://pastebin.com/U5J4RcjR

This my `apt-get upgrade` output: https://pastebin.com/rmyweFV0

I don't have any PPA sources enabled. How can I fix this?

Comment: lubuntu uses gnome packages so I do not see a problem. If you don't want them remove them, but take care, you might remove more than you bargained for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubuntu is modified to automatically install **`pulseaudio`**, when the new (current) version of **`firefox`** is installed (`firefox` is upgraded to the new version, which needs `pulseaudio` for the audio system to work.

A side effect of this modification is that several new program packages are also installed, among them gnome program packages.

See this link to a post at the Ubuntu Forums (and some posts before and after that post),

[Re: Firefox 52, PulseAudio, and Lubuntu 16.04 LTS - Just for the record apparently pulseaudio also installs the following packages as dependencies:](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355092&p=13714252#post13714252)